# Access to Azure MySQL Flexible Server from a definite firewall

Tags: mysql, azure, firewall

I created an instance of MySQL Flexible Server on Azure. I need to close public network access and allow it only through a definite firewall.

The firewall has a definite public IP and I can specify it in the MySQL networking section, that's not a problem. The problem comes because I could connect to the DB from anywhere, and I don't know all possible source IPs in advance.

I need to route all traffic through the firewall, so that it'll be coming from a single IP, from Azure point of view. The MySQL server has an FQDN like `<name>.mysql.database.azure.com`.

Unfortunately, I can't specify FQDN in my firewall, only IPs, and IP might change. With a classic MySQL Single Server I would configure the fw rules to allow traffic towards all IPs listed in "*Azure Service Tags*" file for the service/region pair, say `Sql.WestEurope`.

This does not seem to work with Flexible because the resolved IP from its FQDN can't be found among service tags.

How could I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this feature was changed from single server to flexible, no service tag is supported now.

Try using private access with [VNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-networking-vnet) to restrict access to your Azure MySQL Flexible Server to a specific virtual network or subnet.
You can choose to create a new private DNS zone while deploying with private access or use an existing one. You can setup your firewall destination IP if it does not support FQDN.

Comment: Checking if you got the above working.